# Parse Error with MongoCursor::doQuery in php function?

Tags: php, html, sql

When i try to execute this one function, it returns an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM on line 103".

In line 103, it looks like (This is the beginning part of the code)

```
  function get_list($option) 


{

    //$db = new db();

    //$db->getConnection();

    $rs = $this->db->MongoCursor::doQuery($this->sql, $this->sql_params);   //this is the line 103

    $this->resultList = $rs;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't call a static method as part of a chain.  What is `$this->db->MongoCursor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mix static and instance syntax. It would either be:

`$rs = $this->db->MongoCursor->doQuery($this->sql, $this->sql_params);`

or

`$rs = MongoCursor::doQuery($this->sql, $this->sql_params);`

I don't know what framework if any that you are using to tell you exactly what it should be but what I showed you will fix the syntax error.

`$this->db` looks like it might be Codeigniter? But MongoCursor::doQuery() is vanilla PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.doquery.php